# ¿Como exportar base de datos de workbench a phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

Buenos dias
Quisiera saber como se exporta una base de datos de workbench a phpmyadmin.Mas concretamente yo deseo exportar una base de datos de tres tablas

Comment: Tanto Workbench como phpMyAdmin son aplicaciones para gestionar la base de datos. En teoría no deberías exportar/importar nada, sólo configurar las herramientas para que apunten a la misma base de datos.

Comment: Y eso como se haria?ya que me sale un error

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale? ¿Y qué es lo que estás haciendo para que te salga ese error?